# react-share util.inherits is not a function webpack 2

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, react-share

i have the next error when i try to include react-share in my app, all compile fine and if i go to another routes where no is loading this library works fine, but when i include it crash.

```
TypeError: util.inherits is not a function
```

i am using webpack dev server with webpack 2.
i am mocked the next modules

note: i tried to mock utils so because util is not defined in not node env.

```
node: {
    fs: "empty",
    child_process: "empty",
  },
```

Comment: I have the same basic problem. The only other references I could find were [this other stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908420/webpack-dev-server-2-uncaught-typeerror-util-inherits-is-not-a-function) and [this github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1019) which contains some workarounds, though none worked for me.

Comment: I also encountered this problem.
Does anyone have a solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and eventually found that the problem was that I had a folder name 'util' and somehow the webpack mixed it with the function util.inhirits.
i changed the folder's name and now it is OK.